# Jekyll github pages site ignoring .css

Tags: css, git, github, jekyll

At one point this worked. However, i left the project in what I thought was working condition and then come back to find that the formatting is all broken. The repo is available [here](https://github.com/DaveRGP/Pokemon_FieldStudies) and the site hosted [here.](http://davergp.github.io/Pokemon_FieldStudies/)

I've checked my `_layouts/` folder and it has the `/` seemingly correctly set as per the answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253472/jekyll-posts-not-displaying-formatting-correctly-on-github-pages-rest-of-site-i)

Similarly I've set my base URL as this is a project page as per [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906087/jekyll-deployment-on-github-pages-doesnt-format-correctly-no-styling?rq=1)

Possibly something went wrong when I pushed the RMD file in, however I've tried to wind back and push that as the version of the repo, but I didn't see any changes (maybe I did this badly, I'm very new to github, and pretty novice at git).

How can I get my formatting back? The original structure was made using this tutorial on [jekyll and ghpages.](http://jmcglone.com/guides/github-pages/)

FINAL SOLUTION:

After inspecting and testing both answers from LarsW and David_Jacquel, the final fix is as follows:

1. _config.yml - include `baseurl: /Pokemon_FieldStudies`
2. default.html - include `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/main.css">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link is wrong. The first `/` in `/css/main.css` makes it go to the root folder, which is the domain (http://davergp.github.io/) and not the site (http://davergp.github.io/Pokemon_FieldStudies/). Just change it to `/Pokemon_FieldStudies/css/main.css` or `css/main.css`.

Comment: accepted as root answer, updating question with the actual solution implemented

Answer (score 2):

In `_config.yml`, set `baseurl: /Pokemon_FieldStudies`.

An call you css like this : `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ baseurl }}/css/main.css">`

Comment: I've just tested your implmentation, I'm not sure it's worked. Have I done it wrong? Are you sure I don't need the / in the baseurl argument? If I include that then it works, and is a more ideomatic way of supplying LarW's answer

Comment: Now it's broken again. this slow refresh rater is frustrating.

Comment: thanks, + 1, turned out you're approach partially functioned, and definitely put me on the right track

Comment: Sorry it's `baseurl: /Pokemon_FieldStudies` the slash was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your main.css is blank that why the webpage is coming without styling.

[image]

Put this code in your main.css and hope it should work.

```
body {
    margin: 60px auto;
    width: 70%;
}
nav ul, footer ul {
    font-family:'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Sans-Serif';
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul li, footer ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family:'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Sans-Serif';
}
p {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    color: #333;
}
footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    font-size: .8em;
}

ul.posts { 
    margin: 20px auto 40px; 
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

ul.posts li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but my main css isn't blank... https://github.com/DaveRGP/Pokemon_FieldStudies/blob/gh-pages/css/main.css

Comment: His `main.css` is blank because when loading, the browser got error 404

Answer (score 0):

Check the .gitignore file if some how there is excluded CSS files not pushed to the remote repo.